# Trouble with Youtube (and all streaming services)

Tags: xubuntu, flash, youtube, codecs, additional-drivers

First of all i'm a moderate newbie ( just a little more than a newbie :)
I have an old computer that have 2gb of ram and intel atom n455 cpu (dell mini 1018). I want to install a linux distro for daily usage. Using office programs, checking my mails, reading some rss feeds, surfing on web, etc

I tried several distros from lightest window managers to some heavier desktop environments. Such as openbox, fluxbox, flwm, etc to lxde, xfce, etc

(Distros that i tried: Tiny Core Linux, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Debian LXDE, Debian XFCE, Raspbian for PC, Sparky, Crunchbang, Bunsenlabs, etc)

All of them works slowly but usable. (applications cold starts & web surfing was slow) On the other hand Youtube and other video streaming services was laggy. When i want to watch something on Youtube (or other streaming services) videos was laggy (or freezes) but sound was good.

I searched what was the problem. Some people says install flash player, others says install codecs, some other says it's the driver problem.
I tried flash plugin, installing codecs to os, installing codecs to chromium, installing graphics driver, etc. Nothing did solve this.

Btw lately i installed Pale Moon and it's laggy again but more less than other browsers. I tried several browsers like Chromium, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Vivaldi, etc. Best was the Pale Moon and still best it is.

Please help for this situation.
Thanks from now

Note: Latest system i installed is Xubuntu 18.04. I installed again all codecs in Synaptic, all codecs for Chromium and still using the Pale Moon :)

Note2: Kodi's Youtube player better than Pale Moon but i don't want use my pc like an Apple TV. Not usable for my daily usage like that.

Note3: When i check addional drivers always shows me no additional drivers...

Comment: Look at your CPU usage while watching a video with ubuntu's task manager. I feel like your CPU usage is capping out in all the above cases, if so, there may not be a proper solution as the CPU in the PC may simply be too lackluster to run HD Video. It could also be that the integrated graphics can't keep up, but I'd look at that second.